# Meaning of “Bloody Beautiful”

Tags: meaning

*I moved my question from [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/):*

This [article](https://magazine.cucumbertown.com/the-beginners-guide-to-composition-in-food-photography-how-to-transform-your-food-photos-from-good-39613ab78bf2#.zh17xvvs6) has the title "How to Transform Your Food Photos from Good to Bloody Beautiful".

What does "Bloody Beautiful" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some meanings of 'bloody' are really about blood, but this 'bloody' is a slang intensifier meaning approximately 'very, very, with extra feeling'. 'Bloody beautiful' means 'very, very beautiful'. It can be used in a good way, as here, or in a bad way, such as 'bloody awful'. A good dictionary should include this meaning alongside the ones which are really about blood: 'a bloody knife found at a murder scene'.